# btrfs mount with compress fails with udisksctl but succeeds with mount?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, compression, udisks, zstd

```
$ sudo mkfs.btrfs -fL borgbackups /dev/vgxubuntu/borgbackups
$ udisksctl mount -o compress=ztsd:15 -b /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-borgbackups
Error mounting /dev/dm-3: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.OptionNotPermitted: 
Mount option `compress=ztsd:15' is not allowed
```

But then:

```
$ sudo mount -o compress=zstd:15 /dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-borgbackups /mnt/sd
```

succeeds:

```
$ mount | grep borgback
/dev/mapper/vgxubuntu-borgbackups on /mnt/sd type btrfs 
(rw,relatime,compress=zstd:15,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/issues/704) (or a design decision to be more precise) in UDisks which was fixed in the 2.9.0 release where the `compress` option is allowed for btrfs and additional mount options [can be configured in a config file](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/mount_options.html).

Unfortunately there isn't a workaround other than updating UDisks, older releases have hardcoded list of mount options that can be passed to the `udisksctl mount` command and other options are not allowed.